# Error when installing Composer with SSH on putty

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm new to Putty and SSH.
I followed instructions from https://getcomposer.org/download/ to install Composer with Putty.

The following is the instructions mentionned:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

But i got error on the line:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

telling `Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r`

My PHP Version (`php -v`  output):

```
PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul  7 2021 07:43:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies
```

How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What does `php -v` yield?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `php -v` to your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here are the response: PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul  7 2021 07:43:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies

Comment: To give a better suggestion apart to use a PHP version that is compatible with the composer installer script (PHP 5.3.6+ IIRC), check with your system if that is the only PHP command available or you have more (often with the major version, e.g. `php5`, `php5.6`  or `php7.4`). You will need such a PHP version not only to install but also to run Composer. And wow: I've not seen a PHP 4 version for a long time apart from https://3v4l.org/. Double check you have installed it not in error (the build date suggests otherwise, just take care to use the right one).

Comment: Wow, where did you find PHP 4 in December, 2022?

Comment: it's strange, i use ionos server which has php v7 when i upload scripts but ssh still use php 4